# Can I pass an upload file from vbscript to vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vbscript, multipartform-data

I have a Classic ASP (vbScript) solution that needs to upload files to the server based on a record in the database. The ASP page adds a new record to the database, and then should pass the file (that it received from a multipart form) to the VB file who should upload it.

Considering the recent trouble with vbScript multipart/form-data, we've decided to use VB.NET just for the upload. Can this be done?